# Viewing Crystal Reports other than through custom developed webform or winform apps

Tags: asp.net, winforms, crystal-reports

At work we currently have a custom in-house built winforms app for the business users to view reports. It has role-based security and several administrator functions.

My boss is thinking about getting me to port this app to webforms.

My question is, are there options other than custom built winforms and webforms apps for deploying/viewing/administrating Crystal Reports at an enterprise level (role-based security, easy report deployment, etc)? I'm thinking about third-party packages or perhaps applications provided by Microsoft/Business Objects/SAP?

We are using Crystal Reports 11.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy [Crystal Reports Server](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sapbusinessobjects/sap-crystal-solutions/information-infrastructure/sapcrystalserver/index.epx).